# Signing kernel driver

Tags: windows, window, driver, code-signing

I have developed an intermediate network driver which sits between the low level NIC card driver and the TCP protocol driver. It is basically for network load balancing.

Now, we are in the process of signing for release it to production. Starting with Windows 10, version 1607, Windows will not load any new kernel-mode drivers which are not signed by the Dev WHQL Portal.

What I would like to know, is this really necessary as I dont have any hardware directly interacting with it or shall I proceed signing with the old method of getting the SPC certificate and do signing on my own.

Doing any kind of test involves getting the certificates which incurs some cost. So, suggestion will be off great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the enforcement using bcdedit.exe for testing. For production, it's a requirement.

However, it does not incur any extra cost, as WHQL certficates only require an EV certificate which was already required.